# plot a lat/long coordinate in the map for free or for less cost

Tags: dictionary, plot, location, coordinates

Would like to check if there is any free or less cost service available to show a location in the map? Currently, in one of our clients website, there is a requirement to show the current location- this location is however obtained by one of clients own program. However since its just a plotting of co-ordinates in the map, the client is not willing to invest on license provided by Google or by Bing; because the license given by these guys are for the entire API and in this case there is no need for the entire API as the locations lat/long are already available. And since our client charges the consumers a fee not just for the map but for various other functionalities , there is an ask for a proper license. Any idea or thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

incase you would want to just show a map with a location, then have a look into [Map Image API from HERE](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-image/common/credentials.html).

Also check the limitations for free usage from: http://developer.here.com/get-started

And if you need more dynamic usage HERE has also the [JavaScript API](http://developer.here.com/get-started) for maps available.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. by thelooks of it, i guess it will suit the requirement. I shall anyways let you know how it goes. Thanks Again